# Create a grid with user input size over an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add grid lines over an image, after the user inputs the row and column number. But I am too new to html JS CSS.

for example:

```
<img src="web-image/preview.jpg">
<input type="number" name="row">
<input type="number" name="column">
```

if the user inputs row = 2, and column = 3.
there will be one horizontal line across the middle and 2 lines vertically across one third and two third of "preview.jpg".The grid only needs to be drawings, I don't need to divide the image into parts or make them clickable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with Jquery `.on()` and use `append()`, check this quick code:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.grid table').html('');
  var rows = $('input[name="row"]').val(),
    cols = $('input[name="column"]').val();
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    $('.grid table').append('<tr></tr>')
  }
  for (t = 0; t < cols; t++) {
    $('.grid table tr').each(function() {
      $(this).append('<td></td>')
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.grid {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height:300px;
}
.grid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.grid table td {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <table></table>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300">
</div>
<br>
<input type="number" name="row">
<input type="number" name="column">
<button>Create Grid</button>
```

Comment: glad to help U @mctang719

Answer (score 0):

In your JS you can use blur or keyup to detect when the user is done with the field. I'm not sure exactly what you need in terms of grid lines, but this just adds horizontal bars. You can replace the

---

s with whatever you need.

```
$('input[name="row"]').blur(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 2){
     //add your bars
     $('body').append('<hr><hr>');
   }
});
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is like this: https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-grid.html, instead, I want the user to type in the numbers of rows and columns and then click a button to make the grid display over the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways to do this but this should be fairly easy to follow. And it was fun!

```js
// Reference used elements
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var btn = document.getElementById('update');
var rows = document.getElementById('rows');
var cols = document.getElementById('cols');

btn.addEventListener("click", drawLines);

function drawLines() {
  // Clean up
  removeLines();

  var rowCount = rows.value;
  var colCount = cols.value;
  var wrapperHeight = wrapper.clientHeight;

  // Create rows
  for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var line = document.createElement('div');
    line.className = 'line row';
    line.style.top = (wrapperHeight / rowCount) * i + 'px';

    wrapper.appendChild(line);
  }

  // Create columns
  for (var i = 1; i < colCount; i++) {
    var line = document.createElement('div');
    line.className = 'line column';
    line.style.left = (wrapperHeight / colCount) * i + 'px';

    wrapper.appendChild(line);
  }
}

function removeLines() {
  var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');
  while (lines.length > 0) {
    lines[0].parentNode.removeChild(lines[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}
.row {
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.column {
  width: 1px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="img" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>

<input id="rows" type="number" name="row" placeholder="Rows">
<input id="cols" type="number" name="column" placeholder="Columns">
<button id="update">Update</button>
```